# I don't know how to decipher this string of letters

Tags: cipher

The string of letters is:

> eeeeeeeeeepaeaeeeaeeeeeeeaeeeeeeeeeeccccisaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeejiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjeeeeeeeejcceejaaeeeeeejiiiijiijiiiiiiiijeeejeeeeeeejeeeeeeeej

This is from an Android game Hidden secrets. This is all the puzzle tells you and you're supposed to find an answer, which is a simple english word or phrase. I don't know what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would help? There can be a lot of information to be found in the context. From how the letters are spaced / separated to lines, its colors, background decorations, even the font itself might give a hint on what kind of puzzle it is.

Comment: Me when I stub my toe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a hint from the [Hidden Secrets Discord group and Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HiddenSecretsApp/comments/7mijsy/hidden_secrets_discord_link/)

The hint is

> 1. The question is a cypher of [Brainf*ck code](https://www.dcode.fr/brainfuck-language)
>   2. e=+ and i=-

Filling in the rest of the puzzle you get

> ++++++++++[>+>+++>+++++++>++++++++++<<<<-]>>>>+++++++++++++++.--------------..++++++++.<<++.>>++++++.----.--.--------.+++.+++++++.++++++++.

and this leads us to the final result

> Executing the program will print to console `seem somehow`

Comment: Well done! The "phrase" looks as if it were only a part of a larger message. Perhaps the OP can provide more context?